# Can't compare password with hash Passport NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create function which will changing password. So in first place I have to compare old password with actually user password in db. Here is the problem, I write inside router function but it is not called. Can someone help me, and tell how could I call it to get answer that old password is equall with password user?

```
router.post('/change-password', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body)
       User.comparePassword(req.body.oldPpassword, user.password, function (err, isMatch) { 
          if (err) throw err; 
          if (isMatch) { 
            return done(null, user); 
          } else { 
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' }); 
          }
        });
});
```

Comment: What does `comparePassword` do? Post the code.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be saving the password in the DB, that is unsafe. You should hash it in node and then save the hashed password to the DB. Then when you want to check a user, you hash the new password they gave you and compare that to the hashed one in the DB. You never, never store unhashed passwords. That is a recipe for disaster.

Libraries like bcrypt make this easy.